# Can I make a portion of JS run continously?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm working on an electron app(first time using electron). I'm also very new to javascript so please excuse my stupidity.

In the index.js file I have this method to check if a network connection exists and update a div element accordingly-

```
function checkStatus() {
  var online = navigator.onLine;
  if(online){
    $(".net-status").html("<i class=\"fa fa-globe fa-2x\"></i> Connected");
  }
  else{
    $(".net-status").html("<i class=\"fa fa-globe fa-2x\"></i> Not Connected");
  }
}
```

I want this to run continuously and as soon as the user disconnects from the internet, change the text to "Not Connected"

I tried using a onkeypress event listener in my index.html file but couldn't get it to work.

Also I'm wondering if there is a better way to achieve this purpose than an event listener.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are event listeners available that fire when there is a change to that variable

```
window.addEventListener("offline", function(e) {
    $(".net-status").html("<i class=\"fa fa-globe fa-2x\"></i> Not Connected");
});

window.addEventListener("online", function(e) {
    $(".net-status").html("<i class=\"fa fa-globe fa-2x\"></i> Connected");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The specific case you were asking about can be solved as @juvian said (handling the events provided).

The more general case of "how can I make code run continuously" can be handled with a `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.

Using your function this way would be to set an interval to fire say every half second (the unit is in ms):

`setInterval(checkStatus, 500);`

`setTimeout` works the same way, except that rather than firing continuously every x seconds, it fires once after x seconds.  Still very useful for e.g. polling operations, in that you can set a new timeout each time the poll fires, which has the subtle but important difference from setInterval that it would be x seconds after the request is complete, rather than firing x seconds regardless of how long the request takes.  Doing polling with setInterval can lead to resource contention.